# Lighting Effects changes to black when save to JPEG

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm fed up with an issue (It should be) in which if we have some light effects on a  layer, after saving to JPEG or even on flattening the layers, it just saves a black background and what ever we did on background effects getting lost. (Filter → Render → Lighting Effects)

After some googling I tried Un-checking **Use Graphics Processor** under Preferences → Performances. I updated my Graphics Driver as well. Still the Lighting Effects not being saved.

Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Probably you will not get good answers here. If I use lighting effects as smart filters, they come out properly rendered if I save as JPG. One can only guess something without having access to your files and system.